# Not able to add column in content query webpart

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, custom

I have one root site and three sub - sites each contains document libraries in it.

I put the content query web-part in the root site querying to the sub-site's document libraries. My problem is that I want to display the File Name along with its size. So, referred [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457%28v=office.12%29.aspx) MSDN article to add the column in the content query web part.

The changes I made after exporting is:

`<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string"> FileLeafRef,File; FileSizeDisplay,Computed </property>`

&

`<property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string">FileLeafRef,File; FileSizeDisplay,Computed </property>`

as recommended in the article.

But after importing the customized web part it shows the description only.

What should I do to display those two columns?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is a typo error in `DataColumnRenames` property.

Since you are displaying `File Name (FileLeafRef)` along with its `size (FileSizeDisplay)`, the proper value for `DataColumnRenames` property would be:

```
<property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string">FileLeafRef,Title;FileSizeDisplay,Description</property>
```

### About DataColumnRenames property in CQWP

This property is used to map internal column names to the new column names in the XSLT transformations after the data has been retrieved.

> The default XSLT transformations can render the following four fields:
>   `Title`, `Description`, `LinkUrl`, and `ImageUrl`. In your DataColumnRenames
>   property, verify that the names you specify match the names in the
>   XSLT transformations; that is, `Title`, `Description`, `LinkUrl`, and
>   `ImageUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

While the method you have used to include the columns should still work it is no longer necessary with 2010.  However, just including the column is not enough, you also need to add the XSLT to display it.

There is a post on my blog which should point you in the right direction http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/cqwp-and-xslt-part-1/